# Using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have been gone through [Using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver in Android][1]

I copied the same code in Android project.It is running without error. but no notifications are showing.

Any suggestions?

I searched on internet and found  following method

```
    private void showNotification(Context context, String text) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

I called it as foloows:

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Button notifyButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notifyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        notifyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      showNotification(MainActivity.this,"Hi Parth Here");
        }
    });
}
```

But it is showing error that

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required:
>   pkg=com.example.alertmanagerexample id=1
>   notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code....

```
  String title=extras.getString("title");
    String note=extras.getString("note");
    Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_launcher, "this is    important", System.currentTimeMillis());
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent intent=new Intent(context,urnextactivity.class)
    PendingIntent  pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, pending);
nm.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working.. Actually the code i was using requires API 11.I got it. I was using API 9.

Answer (score 0):

You must supply an pending intent using the `setContentIntent(PendingIntent)`

Please see [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

just add this before `mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());`

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);
mBuilder.addAction(icon, title, intent);
```